# How to add a new slave in Jmeter distributed testing?

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed-testing

Currently I am using Jmeter for distributed testing with a fixed number of slaves specified in jmeter.properties file.
I want to add a new slave dynamically which will report its statistics to the master which is already running.
For example, currently I am running 3 slaves and 1 master and want to add a 4th slave about about which I have not specified in the jmeter.properties file.

How can I do that ? How will the server know about the existence of the new slave so that it collects statistics from the 4th slave also ?

Comment: Were you able to do this? I have the very same requirement.

Comment: Nope, wasn't able to do it. Figured out a way around this problem. But don't remember exactly what it was, currently.